# Can we use $in in mongodb for matching atleast N keywords in mongodb array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have  documents like

```
{
 "attributes":["smart","tall","handsome","etc"]
},
{
 "attributes":["smart","clever","handsome","etc"]
}
```

and I want to search keywords=["tall","smart","xyz"]

if attributes array has atleast two matched keywords then it should be included in records like

```
{
 "attributes":["smart","tall","handsome","etc"]
}
```

should be in answer but not

```
{
 "attributes":["smart","clever","handsome","etc"]
}
```